# Using Proj4js in Openlayers - Proj4js is not defined

Tags: openlayers-2, proj4js

I want to use Proj4js.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.12/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.3/proj4-src.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
....

    Proj4js.defs['EPSG:31466'] = 'xyz';
....
 </script>
```

I get a javascript error: `ReferenceError: Proj4js is not defined`. When I look at the source specified at `/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.3/proj4-src.js`, I do not see any specification of an object called `Proj4js` having a property `defs`. Still, that is what the tutorials are saying (like http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example).

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two choices

**Solution 1:**

You can change the reference to proj4js. OpenLayers 2.x default support is with Proj4js 1.1 whereas you use 2.x.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/1.1.0/proj4js-compressed.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Correct datum for potsdam (altough already corrected with changes in towgs84 in the projection declaration)
      // Only useful if you use the outdated spatialreference.org proj4js definition whereas epsg.io is right...
      Proj4js.Datum["potsdam"] = {towgs84: "598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7", ellipse: "bessel", datumName: "Potsdam Rauenberg 1950 DHDN"};
      // Declare projection. Definition comes from http://epsg.io/31466/
      Proj4js.defs["EPSG:31466"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6 +k=1 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs";
      console.log(Proj4js.defs["EPSG:31466"]);
      var proj_wgs84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
      var proj_31466 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466");
      // Center for projection EPSG:31466
      var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(2769212.70, 5678724.61);
      var new_point= point.clone().transform(proj_31466, proj_wgs84);
      console.log(new_point.lat, new_point.lon);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Demo 1](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/90443226d455ac72638d) (open the browser console to see)

**Solution 2:**

Or you can use the new proj4js version by adding a wrapper to match previous version behaviour:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.3/proj4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //Snippet comes from http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/OL-2-13-1-latest-Proj4js-td5081636.html
      window.Proj4js = {
        Proj: function(code) {
          return proj4(Proj4js.defs[code]);
        },
        defs: proj4.defs,
        transform: proj4
      };
      // Definition comes from http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/31466/
      proj4.defs["EPSG:31466"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=6 +k=1 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs";
      console.log(Proj4js.defs["EPSG:31466"]);

      var proj_wgs84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
      var proj_31466 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31466");
      // Center for projection EPSG:31466
      var point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(2769212.70, 5678724.61);
      var new_point= point.transform(proj_31466, proj_wgs84);
      console.log(new_point.lat, new_point.lon);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Demo 2](http://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/7ffb661dd1e110b7ec8b) (open the browser console to see)

You may encounter some border effects although it seems minor according to [the thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/OL-2-13-1-latest-Proj4js-td5081636.html) about OpenLayers 2.x support with Proj4js 2.x series

There was small difference between both results but now it's OK. It was due to parameters correction with proj4js for this particular projection (EPSG:31466).

Comment: I take solution 2. What I get is: TypeError: `this.proj is null`

Comment: I can't do anything. It's related to other parts in your code: I've added demos links and they both work with the exact same code as the inline code in the answer.

Comment: Solution one seems to work,  but I get `NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myserver.de/myfolder/defs/EPSG3857.js"` as soon as I add `<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/1.1.0/proj4js-compressed.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @ThomasG77 I doubt that `+datum=potsdam` is implemented in Proj4js. I would suggest to use the correct `+towgs84` in any case.

Comment: Ok, I see. You can download proj4js 1.1 http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/wiki/Download and reference it instead of remote proj4js (there are implicit calls to some default projections with proj4js 1.1)

Comment: @AndreJ Can you tell me more? Not from Germany so a bit confuse except I understood that potsdam is not supposed to exist (although it works magically). I only use the spatialreference.org definition. I know `potsdam` exists in v2.x for sure https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/blob/932ca6296d7b09d7695a012b11c9fe8ee43262e7/lib/constants/Datum.js#L26 and also in 1.x series http://svn.osgeo.org/metacrs/proj4js/tags/proj4js-1.1.0/lib/proj4js-combined.js

Comment: Ah, it is hardcoded. But 1.1.0 has `606.0,23.0,413.0`. That was inaccurate and changed in original proj 2 years ago to `598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7`. See http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=12723 for all possible values.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded it and added it. Still, I get `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myserver.de/myfolder/proj4js/lib/defs/EPSG3857.js"`  and `http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3857/proj4js/"`. Looks like the fist 404 problem appears in `EPSG3857.js` if that may help.

Comment: It seems you have to copy `proj4.defs["EPSG:3857"] = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs";` in a new file EPSG3857.js in the defs directory. Not really clean but it's because EPSG code 3857 was introduce later...

Comment: @AndreJ Corrected for old version e.g 1.1.0 So both results output are the same now. Thanks

Comment: This code is misleading.  The Proj4js.defs reference is really just a reference to proj4.defs.  It also doesn't complete the adapter interface.  At a minimum it needs to provide a srsCode getter.

Answer (score 1):

For ol 2.13.1 and proj4 2.3.7 this code allows the scaleline and getGeodesicLength to both operate correctly:

```
/**
adaptor for ol2 to consume proj4 2.x 
*/
var Proj4js = window["Proj4js"] = window["Proj4js"] || {
    Proj: function(code) {
        var result = proj4(code);
        result.srsCode = code; // for ol2 compatibility
        return result;
    },
    defs: proj4.defs,
    transform: proj4
};
```