# Using Proj4js with OpenLayers to transform lat lng from 4326 to 27700 but coming out unchanged

Tags: openlayers-2, proj4js

Using Proj4js to transform lat lng from 4326 to 27700 but coming out unchanged. I am using OpenLayers 2.12 (OS API Leisure map) EPSG 27700, Proj4js (CDN)

I have added the definition to proj4

```
epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); //WGS 1984 projection 
        // To
        proj4.defs("EPSG:27700","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs");
        EPSG27700 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:27700");


        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-0.1279688, 51.5077286).transform(epsg4326, EPSG27700);
        console.log(lonLat);
```

lonLat is coming out as  {lon: -0.1279688, lat: 51.5077286} so unchanged.

I think I'm missing a trick.

Answer (score 2):

`transform` converts the point **in place** so no new point is returned. See the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html#OpenLayers.LonLat.transform):

> Transform the LonLat object from source to dest.  This transformation is in place: if you want a new lonlat, use .clone() first.

So you want something like:

```
    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-0.1279688, 51.5077286);
    lonLat.transform(epsg4326, EPSG27700);
    console.log(lonLat);
```

Comment: The transformation is in place, but it still returns the result, for example in `map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-0.1279688, 51.5077286).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()));`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however both still output the original lat/lng

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers 2 uses an earlier proj4 (version 1.1.0) syntax:

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27700"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs ";
```

or with proj4 version 2:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.12/OpenLayers.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      window.Proj4js = {
        Proj: function(code) {
          return proj4(Proj4js.defs[code]);
        },
        defs: proj4.defs,
        transform: proj4
      };

      proj4.defs("EPSG:27700","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs");

      var epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
      var EPSG27700 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:27700");

      var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-0.1279688, 51.5077286).transform(epsg4326, EPSG27700);
      alert(lonLat.lon + ' ' + lonLat.lat);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are using the OS API some transforms are built in http://openspace.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/4.0.0/files/OpenSpace/GridProjection-js.html

Comment: We were using the openspace api but are migrating to the OS API https://apidocs.os.uk/docs/os-maps-overview so have to remove the OpenSpace reference

Comment: see also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120021/using-proj4js-in-openlayers-proj4js-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out my issue. I looked at the post Mike shared [Using Proj4js in Openlayers - Proj4js is not defined](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120021/using-proj4js-in-openlayers-proj4js-is-not-defined) and tried the example code in my project which still failed. That narrowed it down to the js references. So I copied the references and et voila; success!

My references:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4-src.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.12/OpenLayers.min.js

Changed to:
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/1.1.0/proj4js-compressed.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.13.1/OpenLayers.js

Note that it worked with both versions of OpenLayers js file but not when using 2.5.0.

Thanks to Ian and Mike for helping!

Comment: 2..5.0 is working for me.  I've added the code to my answer.

Comment: Working with mine now too. Thanks Mike!